# Event handling for geometries in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, event-handling, dom-events

I am looking for some kind of event handling for geometries/cameras/lights (things we add to scene) in three.js ?

I Googled but couldn't find anything relevant. I did a simple Sphere rendering and tried to see the DIV contents in firebug, but there's just one canvas, and adding any `onclick` to the canvas makes the event for all the canvas, that is, its not just for the sphere or light.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to a couple o things to get interactivity in 3D:

1. get a vector for the mouse position
2. unproject the mouse vector based on the camera
3. shot a ray from the camera position, towards the unprojected mouse vector
4. check what object(s) interesect with that ray and update accordingly.

It might sound complicated, but the code's already there:

```
function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

                event.preventDefault();

                var vector = new THREE.Vector3( ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1, 0.5 );
                projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );

                var ray = new THREE.Ray( camera.position, vector.subSelf( camera.position ).normalize() );

                var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( objects );

                if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

                    intersects[ 0 ].object.material.color.setHex( Math.random() * 0xffffff );

                    var particle = new THREE.Particle( particleMaterial );
                    particle.position = intersects[ 0 ].point;
                    particle.scale.x = particle.scale.y = 8;
                    scene.add( particle );

                }

                /*
                // Parse all the faces
                for ( var i in intersects ) {

                    intersects[ i ].face.material[ 0 ].color.setHex( Math.random() * 0xffffff | 0x80000000 );

                }
                */
            }
```

This code above from the [canvas_interactive_cubes](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/canvas_interactive_cubes.html) example that comes with the library.
When in doubt, it's always good to check if there's an example that solves the problem already.

[image: canvas_interactive_cubes sample preview]

Comment: That demo doesn't work for me. I click on the cubes, but nothing happens. Did it break since 2012?

Comment: I doubt it. what browser are you using (maybe it doesn't support Canvas very well ) ?

Comment: Yup. It was recently updated chrome, but it updated again when i opened the About screen. Works now. Yay, I feel like a noob.