# Which HTML 5 Canvas JavaScript to use for making an interactive drawing tool?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to develop a drawing tool using HTML 5 canvas. When I searched for a good HTML 5 JavaScript library, most of them where focused just on generating static images or animations.
What I am looking for is the ability to draw primitive shapes like rectangle, circle etc. and also add click events to them. I should also be able to transform the shapes using handles.

I know I may need to customize some framework, but still.. if there is an existing framework with these features it would be good to know.

I read in some places that SVG will be good for all the interactive stuff I am planning to do more than canvas. Would that be more appropriate?

Comment: What kind of a drawing tool do you want to build? Is it a 2D tool or a 3D tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Paper.js

According to their website:

> [Paper.JS](http://paperjs.org) is an open source vector graphics scripting framework that runs on top of the HTML5 Canvas.

and

> offers mouse handlers for the different actions you can perform with a
> mouse (or touch screen).

#### three.js

Another graphics library in JavaScript is [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js). According to their website:

> The aim of the project is to create a lightweight 3D library with a
> very low level of complexity — in other words, for dummies. The
> library provides canvas, SVG and WebGL renderers.

I'm not sure how good the support is for handling mouse events in the library. The following SO question deals with an example for it: [Event handling for geometries in Three.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145383/event-handling-for-geometries-in-three-js)

Comment: Three.js is a 3D library while Paper.JS is strictly a 2D one.

Answer (score 2):

This looks really suited to your needs: http://fabricjs.com/demos/

Here's an example of a simple square you can move and resize with the mouse: http://fabricjs.com/controls/

From http://fabricjs.com/ :

> Using Fabric.js, you can create and populate objects on canvas;
>   objects like simple geometrical shapes — rectangles, circles,
>   ellipses, polygons, or more complex shapes consisting of hundreds or
>   thousands of simple paths.
>
> You can then scale, move, and rotate these objects with the mouse;
>   modify their properties — color, transparency, z-index, etc. You can
>   also manipulate these objects altogether — grouping them with a simple
>   mouse selection.

Answer (score 1):

[KineticJS](http://kineticjs.com/)

on-site description:

> KineticJS is an HTML5 Canvas JavaScript framework that enables high performance animations, transitions, node nesting, layering, filtering, caching, event handling for desktop and mobile applications, and much more.

It can draw primitive shapes (rectangle, circle, and even blobs)
It has many event handlers (click, hover, drag, etc.)
Then you can also animate them (move, rotate, scale)
Also you can apply filters (grayscale, blur, invert)

You can find much [examples and tutorials here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/category/labs/), and here's one screenshot:

[image: One example of KineticJS]

---

**EDIT**

KineticJS is no longer maintained.

You should also try [Paper.js](http://paperjs.org/) or [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/).

Comment: This library is no longer maintained.